# how to print the keys in the order in nsmutabledictionary ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

I am getting a response from a server and I am saving it in a dictionary like this, I am using an `NSMutableArray` for this purpose.

```
{
    a = "";
    b = "";
    c = "";
    d = "";
}
```

I want to print the keys in the same order as they are returned from the server.

But when I print the keys the order is: `c, d, a, b`.

The code I am using is:

```
for(id key in dic){
    nslog(@"%@",key);
}
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: An NS(Mutable)Dictionary has no "order".  (And the elements in a JSON "object" are not ordered either.)

Answer (score 2):

By nature `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` are unordered. You would not be able to do it this way. I would suggest storing the keys into an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` and then printing out the elements of the array in order.

Comment: for sorting in array i do not have a specific sorting order. I just want to print the keys as they are returned from server.

Comment: So ad the keys to the array in the order that they are returned.

Comment: @user2413621 Pretty sure you could figure that out on your own, considering you figured out JSON parsing.

Comment: @user2413621 I agree with duci9y you can figure that part out on your own. I don't know how your application works and how you are receiving the information. I have answered your question clearly: NSDicitonarys are unordered and you would need to use an NSArray instead.

Comment: i am little bit confuse seeing all the answer on web can u pls help

Comment: Does your server return the information one at a time? Like first a is returned, then b, then c or is it the server returns a, b, and c?

Comment: Well JSON files are unordered by nature so there would be no way for you to be able to order the information in Xcode. I would suggest adding a piece of information to a, b, and c so that you can determine in order to them based. For example if you gave them names like 1, 2, and 3. Even if they were in the order 3, 1, 2 you could reorder them to 1, 2, 3 using if statements.

Comment: @user2413621, please choose my answer!

Answer (score 1):

`NSMutableDictionary` is unordered collection.You can make your own ordered dictionary subclass and adding the keys to array in order they come.

Have a look [here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html) is nice explanation how to make `ordered dictionary`.You can also use this [link](https://gist.github.com/axiixc/948736)

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep the response in an NSMutableArray, where each element is a simple NSDictionary with only one key-value pair.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` are unordered collections.

But you can use [`OrderedDictionary`](https://github.com/nicklockwood/OrderedDictionary).